# pyinstaller AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compat'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I use python2.7.1 and pyinstaller compile a executable exe

pyinstaller compile perfectly but the exe can't run

following is error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_Preview_v4_4.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alphalin\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dw4d2a\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 20, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compat'
[16068] Failed to execute script main_Preview_v4_4
```

I try to figure out what happen about the error

but google result just lead me to pandas error

I am not using pandas in my code so I am so confuse

any device?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the icon file (`.ico`) is **collapsed** or in **incorrect format**. If you try it without the `--icon` argument when running the command in your terminal it might work.

If you try to pass as an argument a different file format, other than `.ico` you will get errors. Take the image you want to use and convert it to an icon.

If you have to specify and icon then try converting a `.png` image to `.ico`. An online converter should do the trick.

Comment: I use '''pyinstaller -F main_Preview_v4_4.py''',and no icon for it ,it's still can't work...